# only community that opens new window when clicking on community in stackexchange pull down menu

Tags: support, bug

Why is this the only community that opens a new browser window when I click on writing community in the Stack Exchange pull-down menu on the top left of the screen?

This happens in Chrome, no extensions and no user scripts. It's happened a few times over the past few weeks but doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: It shouldn't. What browser are you using?  Could an extension or user script be causing problems?  Is this recent or has it always been like that for you?

Comment: chrome.  no extensions no scripts.  it's happened a few times over the past few weeks.  it's only the writers community.  strange as the same code that's in that button is fine with the other communities.

Comment: Not getting this in chrome.

Comment: Not happening today.  It's been on and off since I joined the community.

Comment: and now it's happening again.  the only community in the  list that opens a new window. ?